# How to properly load partialview with devexpress elements into extjs panel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs4, devexpress

I was wondering if it is possible to make partialview with devexpress elements to work properly in Extjs panel. So far I managed to load partialview into Extjs panel.All devexpress controls are rendered in a proper way, however it seems that entire client side functinality of devexpress is gone - there is no reaction on hover, click etc. Here is my code

```
  //loading partialView
     Ext.getCmp('centerPanel').body.load({ url: 'Home/TempView',scripts:true})

//controller
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult TempView()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }    

    }

//TempView
<div>
    @Html.Partial("ToolBarView");
</div>


//ToolBarView
@using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI

 @Html.DevExpress().ReportToolbar(settings => {
    // The following settings are necessary for a Report Toolbar. 
    settings.Name = "ReportToolbar";
    settings.ReportViewerName = "reportViewer1";
    }).GetHtml()
```

Is there any way to make it work ?
Here is my application 
http://www.sendspace.pl/file/591cd7a07e43f15a22759b2

Answer (score 0):

With the ExtJS `contentEl` property you can include any content in a panel.

```
//index.cshtml
<div id="dxGrid">
    @Html.Partial("GridViewPartialView")
</div>

//GridViewPartialView.cshtml
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "DevExGrid";
    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Home", Action = "GridViewPartialView" };
    settings.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);
    settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "function(s, e) { endSizeGrid(s); }";
}).Bind(Model).GetHtml()

//ExtJS code
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    contentEl: 'dxGrid',
    id: 'gridContainer',
    title: 'Devexpress inside ExtJS'
});
```

Keep in mind that if you resize the panel you need to resize the DevEx grid manually. You can achieve this by setting a listener on the panel with the DevEx control on it.

```
listeners: {
    resize: function () {
        adjustGridSize(this, DevExGrid);
    }
}
```

When you interact with the DevEx control it will resize too, that is why you need to specify a clientsideevent called `EndCallBack`.

The implementation of the resize functions looks something like this:

```
function endSizeGrid(sender) {
        var el = Ext.get("gridContainer");
        adjustGridSize(el, sender);
};
function adjustGridSize(aGridPnl, aGridView) {
    aGridView.SetHeight(aGridPnl.getHeight());
    aGridView.SetWidth(aGridPnl.getWidth());
};
```

I hope this will help someone.